# How to extract a System.Drawing.Rectangle from a BitmapImage object?

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage

I'm stuck and I need advice, I've gone down multiple rabbit holes and haven't found any rabbits...  I don't know if this is a conversion issue, resolution issue, or I just need to use different object types, or what.  I'm new to working with images.  Please help me!

I have a WPF application which loads in images of various types, and it loads them as BitmapImage objects.  They are displayed in an image control:

```
<Image Width="70" Height="90" Source="{Binding Path=Source}" />
```

This application provides the ability for the user to draw a rectangle around part of the image, and then the application saves that rectangle as a separate image to disk.  I'm using System.Drawing.Rectangle to store the rectangle object.  Here's a code snippet, which leaves me with just a much smaller portion of the image than the actual rectangle is.

```
Bitmap segment = new Bitmap(item.Width, item.Height);
var g = Graphics.FromImage(segment);
g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, new Rectangle(item.X, item.Y, item.Width, item.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
segment.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The problem occurs when I go to write the rectangle out to a file, because Rectangle is compatible with Bitmap, but not with BitmapImage, at least when it comes to sizing.  When I load my images into BitmapImage it changes their size with the PixelHeight and PixelWidth properties.  It seems to roughly double in size.  I don't know why it does that.  But BitmapImage is more compatible with WPF, so I'm using that.  The straight Bitmap object doesn't have those pixel properties.  And the rectangle is like the regular size (not the doubled up Pixel size).

So I tried using CroppedBitmap since that's compatible with BitmapImage, to get the selected image.  So I got the size increase ratio and increased my rectangle size by that, to create the CroppedBitmap, but the sizing is a little too small.  It's cutting off the outer edges.  "item" is my rectangle.  Here's the code sample for that.  Should I stick with CroppedBitmap and just throw in some padding?  Or is there something else I should be doing?

```
double heightFactor = source.PixelHeight / source.Height;
double widthFactor = source.PixelWidth / source.Width;
CroppedBitmap segment = new CroppedBitmap(source, new Int32Rect(item.X, item.Y, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(item.Width * widthFactor)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(item.Height * heightFactor))));
```

Comment: Thanks @Bayrem.  This was my first question I ever posted and didn't research how to convert the code parts to display like that.

Comment: "But BitmapImage is more compatible with WPF". Actually, BitmapImage is a WPF class, while Bitmap is WinForms. Why are you using any WinForms classes like System.Drawing.Rectangle at all in a WPF application? You can do everything without them. Use CroppedBitmap for copying a certain area from a BitmapSource. If the result is too small, increase the size of the area.

Comment: When you want to crop at exact pixel positions you should probably not stretch the source bitmap in any way. Do not set the Image control's Width and Height, and set Stretch to None. Then you would no need widthFactor  and heightFactor. Or at least take care that this factor is an integer number (e.g. 2) and that it's equal in both directions.

Comment: @Clemens, I'm taking over someone's project. They had all the rectangle drawing stuff done.  So I was hoping I could just use that. I never set the Image control's Width and Height. As you suggested I set Stretch to None.  And it's still off a bit.  I need the placement of the rectangle to be exact.  I'm converting the factor to an integer. Are you saying I should replace the System.Drawing.Rectangle object with a Int32Rect object?

Comment: It turns out that all I needed to do was to multiply my rectangle's x and y by the same factor, and now the position of the clipped rectangle is correct: `CroppedBitmap segment = new CroppedBitmap(source, new Int32Rect(item.X, item.Y, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(item.Width * widthFactor)), Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(item.Height * heightFactor))))